# Table headers are shifting every time I re-populate table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I am populating a html table using an Ajax call. Every time I click on Upload button which re-populates the table, the top header row shifts right. How can I ensure it actually does not happen ?

**HTML** -

```
 <input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary custom-button-width .navbar-right" />
<div id="hello" style="position: relative; margin-top: -10px; overflow: auto; width: 100%; max-height: 550px; align-self: center; overflow: auto;">

</div>
```

**JS-**

```
function populateTable(finalObject) {

var headers1 = ["Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5","Name6",
"Name7","Name8","Name9","Name10",
];

    var obj = resp;
    var table = $("<table id='my-table' />");
    headers1.splice(6, 0, "New Name");
    var columns = headers1;
    columns.unshift('');
    var columnCount = columns.length;
    var thead = $('<thead/>');
    var row_head = $('<tr/>');
    for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
        var headerCell = $("<th/>");
        if (i == 0) {
            headerCell.html("<span id='sort'>ｷｬﾝｾﾙ</span>");
        }
        else if (i == 15|| i==17) {
            headerCell.html([columns[i]]);
            headerCell.addClass("sortable");
        }
        else {
            headerCell.html([columns[i]]);
        }
        row_head.append(headerCell);
    }
    thead.append(row_head);
    table.append(thead);
    var tbody = $('<tbody/>');
$.each(obj, function (i, obj) {
        var row = '<tr ><td><input type="checkbox"  value=' + obj.Name1 + '></td><td>' + ReplaceNull(obj.Name2) + '</td><td>' + ReplaceNull(obj.Name3) + '</td><td>'
             + ReplaceNull(obj.Name4) + '</td><td>' + ReplaceNull(obj.Name5) + '</td><td>' + ReplaceNull(obj.Name6) + '</td><td>' + ReplaceNull(obj.Name7) + '</td><td>'
             + ReplaceNull(obj.Name8) + '</td><td>' + ReplaceNull(obj.9) + '</td><td>' + ReplaceNull(obj.10) + '</td><td>' + ReplaceNull(obj.DisPoNumber1) + '</td><td>' + ReplaceNull(obj.DisPoNumber2) + '</td><td><input name=' + ReplaceNull(obj.Name1) + ' id=in' + ReplaceNull(obj.Name2) + ' type="text" size=15  placeholder="Enter Replacement name" value=' + ReplaceNull(obj.New_Name) + '></td></tr>';

        tbody.append(row)

    });

    table.append(tbody);

    var dvTable = $("#hello");
    dvTable.html("");
    dvTable.append(table);
```

**Ajax** -

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '',
                    async: true,
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset= UTF-8",
                    success: function (response) {

                            populateTable(glResp);

                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        alert("Error in the file format!!");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Try to make this verifiable with a running snippet please. We cannot see what's going on in your source if this thing doesn't run.

Comment: I have reply to your first issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40213011/fix-the-headers-in-html-table-populated-by-ajax/) but you have never reply. Please add a jsfiddle or snippet

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience guys, I got it solved though and I will be sharing the solution here in a while. Thanks.

Comment: @P.Frank Hey Frank! I am sorry I couldn`t reply over there in time. I did now. Thanks!